# inline images with ruby mail gem

Tags: ruby, inline-images

Sorry if I'm missing a good article, but I can't find a good example on how to use inline images using ruby with the mail gem (I'm not using RoR)
The best example I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736878/html-email-with-inline-images-not-rendered-properly-in-iphone), but I don't understand where the `.cid` method comes from.

here's an excerpt from the above mentioned post where the `.cid` method is used.

```
html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body "<img width=597 height=162 id='Banner0' src='cid:#{pic.cid}'>"
end
```

I have the mail gem working and it can send images as attachments but I need them to be displayed inside the email, without having the need to open attachments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mail gem is quite well maintained, so it really helps to look into the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/frames/). Your provided snipped misses an integral part: the definition of `pic`:

```
pic = attachments['banner.png']
```

With this information, you can easily find the documentation on [`attachments`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/Mail/Message:attachments), which will yield this bit:

> You can also search for specific attachments:
>
> ```
> # By Filename
> mail.attachments['filename.jpg']   #=> Mail::Part object or nil
> ```

In the documentation to [`Mail::Part`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/Mail/Part), you will then find the definition of the [`cid`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/Mail/Part:cid) method:

```
def cid
  add_content_id unless has_content_id?
  uri_escape(unbracket(content_id))
end
```

(sadly, this method is not documented, but it's easy to infer that "cid" stands for "content id").

Finally, [RFC2557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557#page-8) defines the usage of CID URIs to identify and reference encapsulated documents (such as images) within emails. This is where

```
body "<img ... src='cid:...'>"
```

comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call `url`:

```
> mail.attachments[0].url
=> "cid:5eac50cfe27e2_373f3fed9e82e044326c3@Samuels-MacBook-Pro.local.mail"

> mail.attachments[0].cid
=> "5eac50cfe27e2_373f3fed9e82e044326c3@Samuels-MacBook-Pro.local.mail"
```